# Cannot create file on NAS

Tags: nas

I have a new Western Digital My Book Live 3TB NAS drive and I need to mount it on my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop.

I have created a directory '/NASRichardsWorkLaptop' (changed its ownership and group to myself, and given it 777 access) and mounted the NAS drive onto that using the following line in fstab:

```
//10.0.0.14/RichardsWorkLaptop /NASRichardsWorkLaptop cifs  defaults 0 0
```

However, as soon as it mounts '/NASRichardsWorkLaptop' becomes owned by root with 755 permissions and then only root can write to it.  I need it to be read write to other users not just root.   Any idea who I can make that happen?

I tried `sudo chmod 777 /NASRichardsWorkLaptop/` but the permissions remain at 755 even after this command (if its mounted), so I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [mount.cifs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs), you will notice a uid parameter (or guid)

- **uid=arg**

  > sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the
  >   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
  >   information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric
  >   uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0.
- **gid=arg**

  > sets the gid that will own all files or directories on the
  >   mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership
  >   information. It may be specified as either a groupname or a numeric
  >   gid. When not specified, the default is gid 0.

Adding the uid (or gid) of your user (or group) to the fstab line will grant you the needed rights.

Comment: @user118406 : Nice to have helped you. In the stackexchange world, a "thanks, that worked" is a +1 or an accepted answer ;)